# How to speed-up trained Tensorflow model with FC layers for production

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I have deep FC model (7 layers, 500 units per layer) and I need to speed up it in the production. Memory requirements don't matter. What tools or approaches can you advise except quantization. There are several works about that with several times speed up, but I can't find any tool for Tensorflow. I found the only tool for CNN compression/speed up.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing software speed depends on reducing bottlenecks. Have you benchmarked your code to find which operations are taking the longest?

In TensorFlow code, it could be [GPUs or CPUs](https://github.com/beopst/tf-performance-tips). The TensorFlow tutorials have a "[Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide)" which list best practices. They include:

> • Build and install from source
>     • Utilize queues for reading data
>     • Preprocessing on the CPU
>     • Use NCHW image data format
>     • Place shared parameters on the GPU
>     • Use fused batch norm

Comment: Yes, I know that. There are technics and tools( at least one from Intel) that can optimize trained model. For example, we can remove unused weights and make network smaller with near the same accuracy.

Comment: @BransDs other techniques from a model perspective that can speed up training/convergence are using dropout layers (less parameters to update) and batch normalization which many people find to decrease the total number of epochs required for the model to converge.